# Unique index or primary key violation , In Spring Boot JPA project

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-boot-starter

org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Unique index or primary key violation: "PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC.CR_BOOK_DTL(BOOK_ID) ( /* key:0 */ 0, NULL, NULL, NULL)"; SQL statement:
insert into cr_book_dtl (aurthor_name,book_name,price,book_id) values (?,?,?,?) [23505-214]

Getting This Error in My Spring Boot JPA Project.
Please Provide Troubleshoot.

Trying to insert record in table

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This means that you are trying to insert a new record into the "cr_book_dtl" table and you are supplying values for the "aurthor_name", "book_name", "price" and "book_id" columns. However, the value you are supplying for the "book_id" column already exists in the table as a primary key or in a unique index, which is causing the constraint violation.

In other words, you are trying to insert a record with a value of "book_id" that already exists in the table.

Try increasing the unique ID and reinserting the record.